# Trapezoidal Rule Estimate (Integration)

Tags: integration

How large should you take $n$ so that the Trapezoidal Estimate for $\int_0^3 \sqrt{x^2 + 1}dx$ is accurate within $10^{-4}$? The choices are:

a. 135

b. 121

c. 151

d. 150

In my solution my "k" is 1, so I am getting an answer of $\boxed{150}$

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct. In general the error for the composite trapezoidal rule applied to the integral $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$, given that $f\in C^2[a,b]$, is: $$|Err_{tot}|=\frac{b-a}{12}h^2f^{''}(\xi),$$ for some $\xi \in (a,b)$.
In your case we have that $f^{''}(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$. So:
$$|Err_{tot}|\leq\frac{3-0}{12}h^2\cdot sup_{x\in(0,3)}f^{''}(x)=\frac{h^2}{4}.$$
Let's impose $\frac{h^2}{4}\leq10^{-4}\Rightarrow h\leq2\cdot10^{-2}$. So: $n=\frac{b-a}{h}\geq\frac{3}{2}\cdot10^2=150$.

Comment: In $f''(x)$, there is a sign error Small typo ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for reporting the typo! :)